# Prettier not formatting the java script code correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, format, prettier, formatter

```
import React from "react";
export const todo = () => { 
return <div > todo works! < /div>;
};
```

this is my settings.json code of Prettier,

```
    {
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
    "*.class": "default"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },

  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Ocean",
  "[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
  },
  "[kotlin]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "fwcd.kotlin"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "workbench.editor.defaultBinaryEditor": "default"
}
```

When I save and format the code, there's always a space between the opening tag and the back slash of div/. due to this error occurring and I am unable to import the todo.js file into the main app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the beautify extension.
Find it in extensions and download.
Then switch your default formatter to beautify.

Comment: I tried it using beautify xtension, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `settings.json`

```
"[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
"[javascriptreact]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
"[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
"[typescriptreact]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
```

Comment: Thanks , After adding these to the json file, the issue still persists.

Comment: Try reinstalling Prettier once and then enabling it for the JS files when prompted. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it still persists. Even when there is no formatter , on saving there develops a gap between < and /. Can you try running the code on your end? if that's okay?

Comment: It seems like there is an extension that is causing that to happen. What extensions do you have installed that affect formatting in anyway at all?